# Common resolution for multiple time axes

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have some environmental data with respect to different time axes (With different resolutions). I want to merge them all with one time axis only (The one having more resolution and manage the environmental data with respect to the same time axis. I have googled about it, but I am only getting timestamp examples. If I do it manually by checking the resolution of each and every time axis and the start time of all time axes, it will consume a lot of time. I am looking for a quick solution. A short version of my data frame looks like this.

```
In [1] import pandas as pd

In [2] file_read = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

In [3] file_read

Out[3] 
Time[s]     v1  Time[s].1   v2
160.84621   0   160.84808   7
161.14613   0   161.14802   7
161.538245  27  161.540085  7
162.01598   27  162.017865  7
162.31589   27  162.317775  7
162.615855  27  162.617735  7
162.915765  27  162.91765   7
163.21574   27  163.217625  7
163.51569   27  163.517575  7
163.81563   27  163.81751   7
164.11554   27  164.117425  7
164.4155    27  164.41738   9
164.71543   27  164.717315  9
165.015405  27  165.017285  9
165.31532   27  165.317205  9
165.65083   26  165.65272   9
165.95025   26  165.95214   9
```

Here I want to have a common time axis instead of two (Time[s] and Time[s].1) and interpolate the values of v1 and v2 accordingly.

Comment: Can you add your slow code to question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Time[s]')
df['v2new'] = df.set_index('Time[s].1')['v2'].reindex(df.index, method='ffill')
df = df.drop(['Time[s].1','v2'], 1)
print (df)
            v1  v2new
Time[s]              
160.846210   0    NaN
161.146130   0    7.0
161.538245  27    7.0
162.015980  27    7.0
162.315890  27    7.0
162.615855  27    7.0
162.915765  27    7.0
163.215740  27    7.0
163.515690  27    7.0
163.815630  27    7.0
164.115540  27    7.0
164.415500  27    7.0
164.715430  27    9.0
165.015405  27    9.0
165.315320  27    9.0
165.650830  26    9.0
165.950250  26    9.0
```